# Bash awk, print and skip certain lines output to another text file

Tags: bash, awk, text

I have an output file for some data and I am only interested in certain data points.

I would like the data in the first 361 lines, then for it to skip the next 541 lines and then repeat this process for the remainder of the output file.

i.e. print 361, skip next 541 and repeat. Any help/advice is welcomed.

Sample:

```
Li            #value        #value     #value         (desired text)

... (361 lines)

Ge            #value        #value     #value       (undesired text)

... (541 lines)

Li (again desired) for 361 lines

Ge (again undesired) for another 541 lines

and so on
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO we encourage users to add 3 points in their question. 1st- Sample of input, 2nd- Sample of output and 3rd- their efforts(in form of code), kindly do edit your question with these details and let us know then.

Comment: That works for the first set, however is it possible to repeat the process of printing and skipping without specifying the line numbers? The file is extremely large (over 4.5 million lines) Thanks!

Comment: While your real input may be very large, the [mcve] you create to include in your question won't be. Come up with an example that's say, 15 lines long that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 902 < 361 {print}' file
```

For every group of 902 (sum of 361 and 541) lines, print the first 361. The `{print}` action was added for clarity (not strictly required as that is the default awk action).

Comment: I want to add 902 is effect of adding 361 and 541 for anyone wondering about its source.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v printmrk=361 -v skip=541 'BEGIN { start=1;end=printmrk } NR == end+1 { start=end+skip;end=start+printmrk } NR<=end && NR>=start { print $0 }' file
```

Set printmrk to number of lines to print and skip, the lines to skip, passing them to awk accordingly. In the begin block, set the start variable to 1 and the end variable to the passed printmrk variable. When the NR is equal to end + 1, we need to reset start and end accordingly, then when the NR is less than or equal to end AND NR is greater than or equal to start, print the line.